# Python code HW- Password check program

Tags: python

Heres my task:
Write a program that sets a password as 'changeme' and asks the user to enter the password and keeps asking until the correct password is entered and then says 'Accepted'. The program should count how many attempts the user has taken and tell them after they have been accepted.

This is what Ive done so far:

```
guess =input('\nEnter your password:    ')
password=str('changeme')
count=1
while guess = password:
    print('\nwrong password. Try again!')
    guess =input('\nEnter you password')
    count += 1
print('\nPassword accepted. attempts taken:' + count)
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

An invalid syntax note comes up. Any suggestions?

Comment: `while guess = password:` this condition is missing something, should be `!=`

Comment: Please post the full error you get - the traceback is going to show you a specific line. Also, `guess = password` is assigning, not comparing. You probably want `!=`.

Comment: The program closes straight away before I can read the error. Any way of stopping that?

Comment: Run it in a terminal or something else that will show you the error upon failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line number where you error occurs should be clearly noted. From my own call:

```
    while guess = password:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In addition, it's a logic error of sorts: you want the user to keep guessing while the guess is incorrect, that is `guess != password`.

Comment: oops, silly me, I had pasted it into my editor incorrectly /embarrassed